# Magento marketplace that uses site-wide "Credits" instead of currencies (USD, CAD, etc)

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1

I am planning to build a marketplace using Magento CE.

- The marketplace would have all items listed in "Credits", and buyers
  have to refill their accounts by buying these "Credits" first,
  using their CC/Paypal/Etc.
- Buyers can then proceed to checkout items with "Credits" in
  their accounts.

I'm wondering if there is an existing plugin/solution that enables such functionality.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi you can use webkul marketplace module with credit management system https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Seller-Credit-Management-System.html

https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html

PS - we are not self promoting our product , we are providing the help for users questions for the correct extension

Answer (score 0):

**Chapter I**
*how I would do it*

I think your best bet is to write a Module which

- adds a custom currency (your credits)
- adds payment options

What I'm thinking is that you're just using Magento as usual with your new currency (which shouldn't cause too much trouble, even though I've never done that). Then in the checkout you do the following:
Instead of your usual payment options, you add your own. In the information below the payment options you could show how much those credits are in "real money" and then have the custom options you made just "redirect" to the real options (which are hidden) after the customer has selected one and wants to pay. So you'd make options which basically just utilize the other options in the backend which are hidden for the purpose that you can display a different amount to the customer.

There are not really drawbacks, but a few difficulties.
For example, if you want multiple "real world" currencies, you'd have to adjust your module so that it allows the customer to choose in which currency he wants to pay.

---

**Chapter II**
*the cleaner but longer alternative*

Admittedly, this is somewhat unconventional, but I don't think there's a better way since doing it "properly" would take way longer.

By properly I mean that you'd have to rewrite large parts of the customer module so that you can save an amount of money for each user (the credits he purchased). Then you'd still have to create a custom currency and in the checkout, you'd need to make sure that you're taking the credits and write a new module for handling this (also, if the user doesn't have enough credits, he'd still need to be able to buy credits from there). All in all, more complicated.

---

**Chapter III**
*the lazy ass way*

[This](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-credits.html) and [this](https://www.google.de/search?num=100&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=wC9&channel=fs&q=credits%20module%20magento&spell=1&sa=X&ei=7QhTVe7GI4jaU8n3gJgI&ved=0CBsQvwUoAA&biw=1317&bih=721) (just use a module which exists but might cost you money)

---

*Hope this makes sense, feel free to punch me if I didn't bring it across.*